# Display inline is not working[all in one line]

Tags: html, css

I want to display in one line that `left right span` and `audio` ! I have tried with `display:inline` don't work! Current is display in one line by one

```css
   div{
        margin: 20% 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background: silver;
    }
    audio{
        margin: 20% 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .left,.right{
        height: 10%;
        width: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        background: #af9380;
        font-size: 40px;
        cursor : pointer;
        margin-top: 10%;
        position: relative;        
    }
    .left{
        float: left;
    }
    .right{        
        float: right;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="left"><</span>
    <audio controls><source src="Lesson6.mp3"></audio>
    <span class="right">></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Width of `audio` is `100%`. Chnage it to `80%` to solving your problem.

Comment: 1) There is no `display: inline` in your code. 2) I guess you want `display: inline-block`. 3) Your audio element is using `width: 100%` , so you how do you expect 120% worth of line width to fit into the same line?

Comment: I said I had tried with inline! Don't work so not write there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: silver;
  padding: 100px 0;
}
audio {
  flex: 1;
}
.left,
.right {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #af9380;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="left">&#8701;</span>
  <audio controls><source src="Lesson6.mp3"></audio>
  <span class="right">&#8702;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First audio have 100% width so they won't be in one line. And audio has 4px padding for both sides so the width should be `80% - 8px` if the left and right will be 10%.

```css
     div{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        background: silver;
    }
    audio{
        width:calc(80% - 8px);
        height: auto;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .left,.right{
        height: 10%;
        width: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        background: #af9380;
        font-size: 40px;
        cursor : pointer;
        margin-top: 10%;
        position: relative;   
        display:inline-block;     
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="left"><</span>
    <audio controls><source src="Lesson6.mp3"></audio>
    <span class="right">></span>
</div>
```